# Error while executing "python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm" in spacy python

Tags: python, windows, nlp, spacy

I am trying to load "en_core_web_sm" in spacy but getting the following error

*Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))*

```
import spacy
from spacy import displacy
from spacy import tokenizer

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Downloading whl file from here [spacy](https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/tag/en_core_web_sm-3.1.0)

and running the command

```
pip install en_core_web_sm-3.1.0-py3-none-any.whl
```

did the trick